# How can I pass variable from one function to another in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.openModal = function (page, size) {
    console.log(page); // this is working

    $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/servers/newRole.html',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
     });
 };

 $scope.hello = function() {
     console.log(page); // need value of page from above function

     var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
     var t = document.createTextNode("ABC");

     btn.classList.add("btn-primary", 'btn-xs', 'btn');
     btn.appendChild(t);

     document.getElementById('Id1').appendChild(btn);
 }
```

I have tried using a global variable and assigning the page to this but it is saying `undefined`.

I can access this variable by calling `hello(page)` inside `openModal`, but that won't work as it will call `hello()` when it's not needed.

I have two buttons and calling openModal function on click of 'btn1', and passing page parameter on this button and then there is another button inside that modal 'btn2', calling hello() on click of btn2.

Comment: You need to show how `hello` and `openModal` relate and how you're calling those functions.

Comment: I have two buttons and calling openModal function on click of 'btn1' and then there is another button inside that modal 'btn2', calling hello() on click of btn2.

Comment: What dont you simply send the page parameter to the hello function ?

Comment: @weedoze that is not working, as I am passing page from click of btn1.

Comment: In function 'OpenModal' you can add `$scope.page = page` - You can then reuse $scope.page anywhere else

Comment: Please first read up about angular and its practices. For example, never do DOM manipulation in your controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.openModal = function (page, size) {
    console.log(page); // this is working
    $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/servers/newRole.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl, //resolved items can be use in this controller
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return page; // this will return value
            }
        }
     });
 };
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
     $scope.hello = function() {
         console.log(items); // Here you can get value  
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Tl;Dr : use your scope, or use a service.**

If those methods are in the same controller:

You should just be able to pass it through a variable:

- Initialize it : `$scope.data = {};`
- Push some data in it: `$scope.data = anything;` or `$scope.data.field = anything`.
- Use it further in your function : `$scope.data ... \\ Do anything`

---

If they're not:

You can use an [AngularJS service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). When you finished your data treatment, you can save it into your service, then getting it back later. View it as a getter/setter for any data you would like. Example:

---

A dummy AngularJS service:

```
var service = angular.module('yourService', [])
    .factory('$yourService', function () {
        var yourdata = {};

        return  {
            setData: function(data)    {
                yourdata = data;
            },

            getData: function() {
                return data;
            }
        };
    });

return service;
```

Then, be sure that you inject it into your controller. Into your first function, you can call your service as:
`$yourService.setData(anyData);`

And get back the data in your second function: `$yourService.getData();`